# Mongoose find query doesn't work even equivalent query works fine on mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm implementing a tag system in my page. When user entry any string it will trigger my express route and try to find the content typed to fill a list and return it as JSON to process the callback. The problem is about moongose, because the query is pretty right and works fine if I execute it on mongo shell.

The query:

```
var token = '/.*' + req.query.search + '.*/i';
Tag.find({ description: token , inactivatedAt: null }, function(err, tags) {
    var tempArray = [];

    if (tags) {
        var counter = 0;

        tags.forEach(function(tag) {
            var dArray = [];

            dArray.push(counter++);
            dArray.push(tag.description);
            dArray.push(null);
            dArray.push(null);
            tempArray.push(dArray);
        });
    }

    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/json'});
    res.end(JSON.stringify(tempArray));
});
```

Even if I query as `description: { $regex: token }` or `description: token` the result is not found. The same query parameters are fine and brings result from the mongo on the shell. E.g.: `db.tags.find({ description: /.*MET.*/i , inactivatedAt: null }).pretty()` but my mongoose query doesn't work.

Any clue will be very helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert `token` into a regular express instead of just a string:

```
var token = new RegExp(req.query.search, 'i');
```

Comment: Also note that any special characters need to be escaped when using new RegExp `/foo\d/` or `new RegExp('foo\\d')`

Comment: If we want to apply on _id then this "new RegExp(req.query.search, 'i');" not work. Anybody know how to solve this?