# Query with like in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How can I do a like query in MongoDB using Node.js?

Here's my source code, but it doesn't work:

```
exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
    var country=req.params.country; 
    db.collection('wines', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find({ 'country': new RegExp('/'+country+'/i') }).toArray(function(err, items) {
            res.jsonp(items);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongoose find query doesn't work even equivalent query works fine on mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804168/mongoose-find-query-doesnt-work-even-equivalent-query-works-fine-on-mongodb)

Comment: Heres I found the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804168/mongoose-find-query-doesnt-work-even-equivalent-query-works-fine-on-mongodb

Comment: you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71136307/14229690

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
 exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
        var country=req.params.country; 
        db.collection('wines', function(err, collection) {
            collection.find({ 'country': new RegExp(country, 'i') }).toArray(function(err, items) {
                res.jsonp(items);
            });
        });
    };
```

Comment: how to use this find regex in dynamic key? ex : var key = request.body.key; find({ key :  new RegExp(country, 'i') });
I've tried this but still the key is considered not as string

Comment: what is 'i' in this?

Comment: case insensitive search

Comment: If we want to apply on mongoose _id then this "new RegExp(req.query.search, 'i');" not work. Anybody know how to solve this?